# Programatically change the materials of an avatar, and only one avatar

Tags: unity, materials

Im using an asset I bought some time ago, and using some models from it. This is the model:

[image]

My question is, how could I dynamically change things like the hair, the uniform, etc? The asset comes with various PNG files for every part of the model (face, hair, shoes, etc.) and I would like the player to be able to shoose a hair, a skin, etc. for the model. I see a list of materials slots in the Inspector where they are set, but don't know how to do it programatically.

EDIT:

I (sort of) achieved what I wanted, this way:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)){
        GameObject polyMesh = selectedUnit.transform.Find("Polymesh").gameObject;
        GameObject model=polyMesh.transform.Find("model_001").gameObject;
        SkinnedMeshRenderer mesh=model.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        Material[] materials = mesh.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
        Material WhiteUniform = Resources.Load<Material>("Materials/WhiteShirt");
        materials[1] = WhiteUniform;
        mesh.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials=materials;
    }
```

Now my problem is that it changes the shirt of all the players. It is possible to change the material of only the selected player?

Comment: I'd assume you tried reading the [renderer.materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) array, replacing the materials you wanted to change, then assigning the result back? Where did you run into difficulty making this work for your use case?

Comment: I didn't actually tried, I am fairly new to Unity and didn't know how to access the materials. By using renderer.materials array, and assigning the materials I create from the textures in the asset to every slot in the array would work? Do they come in the same order that is shown in the Inspector? I should access first to the Player object, then to the Polymesh object and finally to model_001 object, right?

Comment: Those sound like questions you can answer for yourself by trying it. If you hit a snag or unexpected behaviour, **edit your question** to show what you tried and where you need help.